# Is the compile method appropriate for altering the template dynamically in a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive where I want to add a select and either a textarea or an input field depending on some input. For example

```
app.directive('monkey', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div><select><option>1</option><textarea>{{text}}</textarea></div>'
        scope: {
            text: "="
        },
        link: function(element, attrs, scope) {

            // Add listeners etc

        }
    }
});
```

so the html would look something like

```
<monkey text="model.name" type="input"></monkey>
```

I want to be able to look at the type attribute and change my template from

```
<div><select><option>1</option><textarea>{{text}}</textarea></div>
```

to

```
<div><select><option>1</option><input>{{text}}</input></div>
```

Is the compile function what I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could use the compile method for this.

But, if you have a limited set, I would opt for `ng-if` first.  Just because it keeps things slightly more simple.

So the template becomes something like:

```
<div><select><option>1</option><textarea ng-if="type == 'textarea'">{{text}}</textarea><input ng-if="type == 'input'">{{text}}</input></div>
```

So, you would need to take `type` into your directive as well.  Here is the entire directive:

```
app.directive('monkey', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div><select><option>1</option><textarea ng-if="type == 'textarea'">{{text}}</textarea><input ng-if="type == 'input'">{{text}}</input></div>'
        scope: {
            text: "=",
            type: "@"
        },
        link: function(element, attrs, scope) {

            // Add listeners etc

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh yes, of course. Sometimes you miss the obvious. Out of interest how would you use the compile method?

Comment: If you were making significant changes to the template, then compile is the place. Or, if you needed to extend the template in a way unsupported by angular, like dynamic form names.

Comment: I forgot to add. I am watching another value in the scope and if it changes then I need to be able to reference the input or textarea because I am moving the caret position. How would I be able to get the textarea or input from the element? element.children('input')[0]?